How is channel charge calculated in meyer model?
The following is from MOSFET Circuit Models.
$$
q_N^v(v_{GS}) = -w \int\limits_0^L C_{ox}^c(v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C) dy \\
$$
Recalling that current is related to the electric field
$$
\begin{align}
dy &= \left( \frac{W C_{ox} \mu_n}{I_D} \right) n \left( v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C \right) dv_C \\
\\
q_N^v(v_{GS}) &= - \left( \frac{W_C^2 \mu_n C_{ox}^2}{I_D} \right) \int\limits_0^{V_{GS} - V_{Tn}} \left( v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C \right)^2 dv_C \\
\\
q_N^v(v_{GS}) &= -\frac{2}{3} WLC_{ox} (v_{GS} - V_{Tn}) 
\end{align}
$$
$$
I_D = -W \cdot Q_N(y) \cdot v_y(y)
$$
In my opinion, math here is wrong.
It should be the following:
$$
I_D = -W \cdot Q_N(y) \cdot v_y(y)
$$
$$
v_y(y) = -\mu_n \cdot E_y(y) = \mu_n \cdot \frac{dV}{dy}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow 
v_y (y) = C_1 e^{\mbox{$\Large\frac{y} {\mu_n}$}}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
q_N^v(v_{GS}) &= -\frac{W^2 C_{ox}^2 \mu} {I_D} \int\limits_0^L (v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C)^2 d V_c \\[1.5em]
q_N^v(v_{GS}) &= -\frac{2 W^2 C_{ox}^2 \mu} {3 I_D}  (V_{GS} - V_{Tn})^3 
\end{align}
$$

Have you tried to simplify it by substituting the expression for ID?

@internet yes. That will gives 4/3 rather 2/3

Your intergration is wrong. It should be 1/3 and then if you substitue ID = 1/2 uCox W/L (Vgs-Vth)^2 you would get the result they gave.

@internet how about
$$v_y(y) = -\mu_n \cdot E_y(y) = \mu_n \cdot \frac{dV}{dy}$$
$$
\Rightarrow
v_y (y) = C_1 e^{\mbox{$\Large\frac{y} {\mu_n}$}}
$$

This is what I have been saying in the comments:
If you integrate this:
$$
q_N^v(v_{GS}) = - \left( \frac{W_C^2 \mu_n C_{ox}^2}{I_D} \right) \int\limits_0^{V_{GS} - V_{Tn}} \left( v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C \right)^2 dv_C
$$
you should get
$$
\begin{align}
q_N^v(v_{GS}) &= -\frac{W^2 C_{ox}^2 \mu} {3 I_D} (V_{GS} - V_{Tn})^3
\end{align}
$$
Now, substitute
$$
I_D = \frac{1}{2} \mu C_{ox} \frac{W}{L} (V_{GS} - V_{Tn})^2
$$
you should get the expression that the author gave:
$$
q_N^v(v_{GS}) = -\frac{2}{3} WL C_{ox} (v_{GS} - V_{Tn})
$$

Let's go through the derivation step by step to see where any potential issues might be in the original and your corrected versions.
Original Version Derivation

Starting Integral:
\$
q_N^v(v_{GS}) = -w \int\limits_0^L C_{ox}^c(v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C) \, dy 
\$

Relating dy and dv_C:
\$
dy = \left( \frac{W C_{ox} \mu_n}{I_D} \right) \left( v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C \right) \, dv_C 
\$

Substituting dy in the Integral:
\$
q_N^v(v_{GS}) = - \left( \frac{W C_{ox} \mu_n C_{ox}}{I_D} \right) \int\limits_0^{V_{GS} - V_{Tn}} \left( v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C \right)^2 \, dv_C 
\$

Solving the Integral:
\$
\int\limits_0^{V_{GS} - V_{Tn}} \left( v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C \right)^2 \, dv_C = \frac{1}{3} \left( v_{GS} - V_{Tn} \right)^3 
\$

Final Expression:
\$
q_N^v(v_{GS}) = -\frac{2}{3} W L C_{ox} (v_{GS} - V_{Tn}) 
\$


Your Suggested Correction

Starting Expression:
\$
I_D = -W \cdot Q_N(y) \cdot v_y(y) 
\$

Relating v_y(y) and E_y(y):
\$
v_y(y) = -\mu_n \cdot E_y(y) = \mu_n \cdot \frac{dV}{dy} 
\$

Incorrect Exponential Expression:
\$
v_y(y) = C_1 e^{\frac{y}{\mu_n}} 
\$
This step seems incorrect as the velocity in the MOSFET channel typically doesn't follow an exponential form. The velocity \$v_y(y)\$ is usually derived from the electric field and potential, leading to a linear or quadratic relationship depending on the MOSFET region (triode or saturation).

Alternative Integral Form:
\$
q_N^v(v_{GS}) = -\frac{W^2 C_{ox}^2 \mu} {I_D} \int\limits_0^L (v_{GS} - V_{Tn} - v_C)^2 \, dV_C 
\$

Solving the Integral:
\$
q_N^v(v_{GS}) = -\frac{2 W^2 C_{ox}^2 \mu} {3 I_D} (V_{GS} - V_{Tn})^3 
\$


Analysis

Original Derivation:

Correctly starts with \$ q_N^v(v_{GS}) \$ integral.
Uses \$ dy \$ to \$ dv_C \$ relationship correctly derived from charge and current continuity.
The integral result is correctly evaluated, leading to \$ -\frac{2}{3} WLC_{ox} (v_{GS} - V_{Tn}) \$.


Your Correction:

Begins correctly with \$ I_D = -W \cdot Q_N(y) \cdot v_y(y) \$.
The step \$ v_y(y) = C_1 e^{\frac{y}{\mu_n}} \$ is incorrect and deviates from standard MOSFET modeling.
Your integral form \$ -\frac{2 W^2 C_{ox}^2 \mu} {3 I_D} (V_{GS} - V_{Tn})^3 \$ appears to be overly complicated and doesn't align with the physical meaning and standard derivations for MOSFETs.



Conclusion
The original derivation provided is mathematically sound and aligns with standard approaches for MOSFET modeling. The correction you suggested deviates by introducing an exponential form for \$ v_y(y) \$, which is incorrect in this context. Thus, the original version is correct, and no corrections are needed based on standard MOSFET theory.
